# Resize/Crop Image with preview and Save using Blue imp tools?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

I uploaded some images using this Blueimp's awesome plugin [JQuery File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload).

I now want to allow my users to Resize (with a preview) and Crop and Save them using only Blueimp plugins suite.

I know these plugins [JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob), [JavaScript-Load-Image](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image). I want to use them to edit an image from the server as you can see on the below image.
[image]

```
var $imageWrapper = $('#imageWrapper'), currentFile,
coordinates, actionsNode = $('#actions')
replaceResults = function (img) {

var content;
if (!(img.src || img instanceof HTMLCanvasElement)) {
    content = $('<span>Loading image file failed</span>');
} else {
    content = $('<a target="_blank">').append(img)
            .attr('download', currentFile.name)
            .attr('href', img.src || img.toDataURL());
}
$('#watcher').replaceWith(content);
 //console.info(content)
$imageWrapper.children().replaceWith(content);
            if (img.getContext) {
                actionsNode.show();
            }};
$('.profile-update').click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();

var imageUrl = app.basePath + $(this).closest('.view').find('a').attr('href');

loadImage(
    imageUrl,
    function(img) {
        if (img.type === "error") {
            app.noticeBox("Error loading the selected image");
        } else {
            var $cropperWrapperClone = $('#cropperWrapper').clone(true);
            $imageWrapper = $cropperWrapperClone.find('#imageWrapper');
            $imageWrapper.html($(img).addClass('object-border'));

            app.modalBox({
                content: $cropperWrapperClone
            });

            $('#editImage', $cropperWrapperClone).on('click', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                var imgNode = $imageWrapper.find('img, canvas'),
                        img = imgNode[0];
                imgNode.Jcrop({
                    setSelect: [0, 0, 250, 250],
                    onSelect: function(coords) {
                        coordinates = coords;
                    },
                    onRelease: function() {
                        coordinates = null;
                    }
                }).parent().on('click', function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                });
            });

            $('#cropImage', $cropperWrapperClone).on('click', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                var img = $imageWrapper.find('img, canvas')[0];
                if (img && coordinates) {
                    replaceResults(loadImage.scale(img, {
                        left: coordinates.x,
                        top: coordinates.y,
                        sourceWidth: coordinates.w,
                        sourceHeight: coordinates.h,
                        minWidth: $imageWrapper.width()
                    }));
                    coordinates = null;
                }
            });
        }
    }, {
        maxHeight: 500,
        maxWidth: 600,
        //aspectRatio: 16/9
    }
);)};
```

The code above is what I have. How to be able to have a preview of the selected image and save it when user clicks on "Save" button?

I'll really appreciate you help.